# How to construct a windows service asynchronously with TopShelf

Tags: .net, asynchronous, topshelf

I am using `TopShelf` to run a `windows` service and i was wondering what would be a feasible way to build the service if some of its dependencies are `asynchronously` obtained? As far as i checked there is no `Async` overload for `ConstructUsing`

**Service**

```
Class MyService
{
  public string ServiceData {get;set;}
  public static async Task<MyService> CreateAsync()
  {
     var data=await SomeAsyncOperation();
     MyService serv=new MyService(data);
     return serv;
  }
}
```

**Main**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {

            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => {
                x.Service<MyService>(s => {
                    s.ConstructUsing((h) =>MyService.CreateAsync().Result);

                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            });
            int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
            Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue; 
        }
```

Should i just run my service in parallel task via `Task.Run` with an `CancellationToken` defined in the `Main` or should i just use `Task.Result`.
in the `ConstructUsing<>` method?